# I'm trying to write a module to dynamically load other modules . is it correct?

Tags: node.js, express

Main script is app.js :

```
var express = require('express'), app = express() ;


app.use('/:module' , function (req , res) {
     var module = req.params.module ;
     require( './'  + module   )( req , res )
 }) 

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
})
```

And a module is  module.js :

```
var express = require('express'), router = express.Router()

router.get('/:task', function(req, res) {
   res.send( 'Module task is : ' + req.params.task )
})

module.exports = router
```

And finally this address (( http://localhost:3000/module/task )) will be called.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem?

Comment: Have you tested this yourself? Did it work? What were the results/errors and what did you expect?

Comment: Yes . it Work . I want to understand this method is ok ?

Comment: You may want to think about possible security vulnerabilities using this method as the user pretty much has control over what files are loaded